# Error - CKEditor5 collaborative component implementation

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ruby

I have successfully made **CKEditor5** ( Collaborative editing ) component via custom build. But I got the following error when I run index file in browser window.

> CKEditorError: "Observable-bind-to-properties-length: The number of properties must match".

Any help would be appreciated.

[Error screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJfoc.png)

Comment: Did you read through the link the error provided in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

@Mark -

Yes. It says nothing other than "number of properties must match". There is no other details. Screenshot attached.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXGvY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here are docs for the `bind` function: https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_utils_observablemixin-ObservableMixin.html. Note that these docs are being improved now on the [GH](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/pull/253) and you can check the new ones directly there - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/blob/272bebe5f76ede8a8860005dd7671b46a141e877/docs/framework/guides/deep-dive/observables.md